# Обработка(распознавание) событий с экрана в Java

Tags: java, распознавание-символов

Мне необходимо распознать текст с экрана . Например я делаю скрин приложения , в котором что-то происходит. Далее скидываю изображение в любую папку , а Java берет изображение и распознает текст . Есть предположение , что здесь замешаны нейронные сети. Если это так , то может кто знает библиотеку , и как с ней работать (Пример кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для распознавания текста можно использовать tess4j (врапер tesseract). Хорошо распознает текст с изображений, в том числе с отсканированных копий, но в большинстве случаев требуется предварительная обработка документов (распознаются только горизонтальные надписи, поэтому нужно, например, использовать поворот изображения и тд)

```
ITesseract ocrEngine = new Tesseract();
ocrEngine.setDatapath("pathToDictionaries");
ocrEngine.setLanguage("usingLangNames");
BufferedImage bImage = <read image code>;
String text = ocrEngine.doOCR(bImage);
```

Где, pathToDictionaries - обученные модели для распознавания текста для определенного языка (можно взять [с гитхаба](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) ), usingLangNames - список языков, для которых подключены модели и которые нужно использовать при распознавании.